# Tgkill Crash on Cordova Android App

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I am getting a "tgkill" error on my Cordova Android App. This is the back trace reported on Google Play Developer web portal:

```
  native: pc 00000000000221a4  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
  native: pc 00000000000131f9  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
  native: pc 000000000001340d  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
  native: pc 0000000000012143  /system/lib/libc.so
  native: pc 0000000000021a58  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
  native: pc 00000000001a4d2d  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  native: pc 00000000001a2927  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  native: pc 000000000019532d  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  native: pc 0000000000ca3fd7  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  native: pc 0000000000baac09  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  native: pc 0000000000b88f1d  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  native: pc 0000000000b8a993  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  native: pc 0000000000b8d2c3  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  native: pc 0000000000b86ea5  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  native: pc 0000000000cf8715  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  native: pc 0000000000cf84f9  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  native: pc 00000000001b0e39  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  native: pc 00000000001b18c9  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  native: pc 00000000001b1a27  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  native: pc 00000000001c217b  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
  native: pc 00000000000204cc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
  native: pc 0000000000051157  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
  native: pc 0000000000029960  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  native: pc 0000000000030dec  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
  native: pc 000000000002e484  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
  native: pc 000000000006389d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
  native: pc 000000000006b7a3  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  native: pc 0000000000029960  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  native: pc 0000000000030dec  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
  native: pc 000000000002e484  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
  native: pc 00000000000635b9  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
  native: pc 000000000004cd37  /system/lib/libdvm.so
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: is the device running android 4.4?

Comment: ah yes this particular trace happend on 4.4

Comment: I know there was a bug with chromium in android 4.4.2 but was fixed in 4.4.4, is there a way you can update to check if it stops?

Comment: I got this crash information from Google Play developer console. Strangely Google never specify is it 4.4.2 or 4.4.4. Anyway, I guess I will give up on these 4.4 users. Thanks!